# Most efficient way to check flag on server

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm looking to set up a flag on a webserver, just so that I can change something after I release my app to the app store in case a bug doesn't go away. I'm not familiar with network connections, but I've put together the following:

```
- (void) loadThumbnailFlag
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myappsite.com/ThumbnailFlag"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    if ([httpResponse statusCode] / 100 == 2)
    {
        self.thumbnailFlag = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.thumbnailFlag = NO; 
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to improve this code so it's not wasting any steps as just to check if the flag exists or not (i.e. it's not trying to download a file or anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the body, only the response, then it's best to either set the request to type `HEAD` (`[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];` create an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest`), or to call `cancel` on the `connection` in `connection:didReceiveResponse:`.

If the server doesn't actually return any body data then it won't make a big difference, but it makes your intentions for the connection clear.

Comment: Thanks that's a great suggestion. I went with setting the request to head.

Comment: Yes, `HEAD` is also the best match to your situation because you only want the response and headers.

Comment: One more question Wain, do you think this will make a huge difference if the file in question that is being checked for a flag is empty?

Comment: No, it will make things a little faster, that's all. You could say it protects the future just in case the server was changed, but the best thing to protect against that is to set HEAD and cancel the connection (just in case the server doesn't respect the HEAD setting for some reason).